# Append data to newly added column in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I used this line to add a new empty column to my DataFrame

```
df.insert(3, 'Summary', '')
```

Then, I want to fill each raw of this new column with `text` in this loop at the same position of index `i`

```
    with open("drive/MyDrive/First_hotel.txt","a") as f:
      for i in range(number_of_review_per_hotel(Hotel_names[0])) :     
        toSummarize = df['English_reviews'][i]
        text = summarizer(toSummarize, max_length = 10)[0]['summary_text']
        ****
        f.write(text+' ')
```

What should I write in the place of `***`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
temp = df.index
df.loc[temp[i], 'Summary'] = text
```